# Maple differentiation syntax?

Tags: derivatives, maple

If you have assigned a function to a label, how can you take it's derivative? For example I defined `fun2` as $x^3$ but doing `diff(fun2, x)` gives `0`.
[image: screen shot]

Comment: You must write : diff(fun(x),x) .

Answer (score 0):

`fun2:=x -> x^3` assigns a "name" for your *function* that you can reach by writing `fun2(x)`. This is your functions' name from now on, including the `(x)`. Differentiation goes like this:

```
diff(fun2(x),x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `fun2` name has been assigned an operator. So it makes sense to produce an new operator which computes the derivative. The command for doing that is `D`.

```
fun2:=x -> x^3;

                                         3
                           fun2 := x -> x 

dfun2 := D(fun2);

                                          2
                         dfun2 := x -> 3 x
```

Above, I've assigned the result to the name `dfun2`. Notice that I can then apply that to some argument.

```
dfun2(4);
                                 48
```

In contrast, `diff` acts on expressions (not operators) and returns an expression. So what it gets out cannot be immediately applied to an argument. (And it acts on the result of `fun2(x)` which evaluates to the expression `x^3`. It doesn't act on `fun2` itself.)

```
diff(fun2(x),x);

                                   2
                                3 x
```

You could turn the expression back into an operator. But it's so much simpler to just use `D`, which was designed for this.

```
unapply( diff(fun2(x),x), x );

                                   2
                           x -> 3 x
```

There are other more subtle issues that can arise when forcing using of `diff` on a call to `f(x)`. It could be that `f` is not prepared to accept a nonnumeric argument. `D` can still handle this case (and is useful in other corners, too).

```
f := proc(x) if x>2 then x^2 else x^3; end if; end proc:

diff(f(x),x);
  Error, (in f) cannot determine if this expression is true or false: 2 < x

D(f);

         proc(x) if 2 < x then 2*x else 3*x^2 end if; end proc;
```